# What must a Klingon do in order to be considered a Dahar Master?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-tos, klingon, klingon-language

Memory Alpha describes a Dahar Master as:

> a Klingon warrior who had reached a legendary status among his peers and subordinates.

And Memory Beta:

> Dahar Master is the title given to Klingons, who are the best of warriors and have reached legendary status. These warriors are respected by all and the tales of their exploits are often repeated in stories, songs and operas

To me "master" implies that the warrior has mastered some skill, at the very least "Dahar", whatever that is<sup>✝</sup>

Does any series or novel cover what Kor, Koloth, and Kang did to achieve this "legendary" status?

--

<sub>✝ Bing Klingon seems to have no translation for the word</sub>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [The Klingon Art of War](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Klingon_Art_of_War), the title of 'Dahar Master' is ***bestowed* upon a very small number of legendary Klingon warriors by the Emperor, or presumably by the Chancellor.** There doesn't seem to be any special qualification, but all of the recipients mentioned (Biroq, Koloth, Kor, Kang) seem to fit quite a similar mold

- **Their deeds must represent a lifetime of (military) service to the Klingon Empire**.
  Kang was an able commander who captained a number of renowned Klingon vessels. Kor fought numerous battles against the Federation and the Romulans. Koloth patrolled the border of the Klingon Empire for decades and Biroq led his troops into a series of highly successful off-world battles.
- **Their deeds must be noted in song and story.**
  All of the Dahar Masters seem to be particularly lauded by their fellow Klingons and rather fond of their own capacities. It's noted that each of them is a braggart with an inflated opinion of their abilities. Self-publicity and a generous interpretation of the facts (to enlarge their own part in their personal story) is not just tolerated, but *positively expected*.
- **The title is bestowed after an especially important event that exemplifies the cardinal virtues of the Empire; Strength, Duty, Sacrifice and above all things, Honour.**
  Biroq led the conquest of the first world outside the home system, Koloth killed  an especially troublesome pirate, Kor prevented a Romulan invasion and Kang seems to have receive his plaudits after tangling with the Starship Enterprise.

---

One assumes that dubbing someone a Dahar Master is something that a Chancellor might only do once or twice in their entire term of office, so the goal is to pick someone larger than life, whose popularity with the people will then reflect favourably on the person giving them that honour.

Comment: "bestowed upon a very small number" - how contrived that of all Klingon starship commanders in the fleet, the three that we met during TOS's five year mission all belong to that "very small number". Or is it like the various civil national merit awards granted by some countries to the few people who achieved exceptional things in a couple of areas - i.e. several thousand each year?

Comment: "Biroq led the conquest of the first world outside the home system" - what worlds could be *conquered* inside the home system? Were there any other inhabited worlds in the Klingon home system? And who is Biroq, given that Memory Alpha doesn't appear to know about him?

Comment: "something that a Chancellor might only do once or twice in their entire term of office" - do we know how long or short Klingon chancellors' terms of office are?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Biroq may not be known on Memory Alpha, but he is known (barely) on [Memory Beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Dahar_Master), the non-cannonical Star Trek wiki.

Answer (score 0):

Kor, Master Dahar, died in battle with the Jem'Hadar at Trelka Five in 2375, he accepted a suicide mission on board the Ning'Tao and by sacrificing his life he save the lives of his comrades.

The victory against the Romulans that someone mentioned was way before his death. in 2270 during the Battle of Klach D'Kel Brakt and it was then when he was awarded the title of Dahar Master.

And yes, this title is only bestowed upon a deemed legendary Klingon warrior only by the Chancellor or Emperor (depending on what period in the history of the Klingon People he or she lived in).

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This doesn't seem to add anything to the existing answers, and appears to be more of a comment.  Please don't post comments as answers; when you earn some reputation you'll be able to leave comments.  You might want to take the [tour].