# After a period of time, would Worf be considered a Dahar Master?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, klingon, worf

After all that Worf has done, all for the sake of the Empire, would he not deserve the title of Dahar Master?

Comment: It doesn't seem that any canon source has laid out the actual requirements or process for becoming a Dahar Master, aside from a vague suggestion of "be a legendary Klingon warrior". We could speculate about reasons for or against, but there doesn't seem to be any definitive answer.

Comment: As the link shows Worf would not qualify as most of his service was in Starfleet rather than the Klingon Fleet.

Comment: @Cadence - It's highly unlikely that Worf would qualify since he's very averse to self-publicity and positively despises people enlarging their own part in battles; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/145841/what-must-a-klingon-master-do-in-order-to-be-considered-a-dahar-master